# Understanding the type of (,) <$> length <*> head

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, applicative, type-signature

I have this pair of functions

```
(,) <$> length :: Foldable t => t a -> b -> (Int, b)
```

and,

```
head :: [a] -> a
```

I would like to understand the type of

```
(,) <$> length <*> head
```

In `(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` type signature,

`f :: (->) [a]`

`a :: b`

`b :: (Int -> b)`

So, the instantiated type would be:

```
(->) [a] (Int, b)
```

However, I found out really its type is:

```
(->) [a] (Int, a)
```

Two questions, if I may:

- Why is the `b` switched for an `a` ?
- What's the step by step process in this type signature calculation ?

Comment: You should probably use different letters for the types in the first signature and the types in the second signature so that it doesn't get confusing. Also, the `=` sign in types is written like `~`, not like `::`

Comment: `a :: b` isn't correct. `a` is *unified* with `b`, not a value of type `b`.

Comment: Thank you, @chepner, What does _unified_ mean, in this context ?

Comment: It just means `a` and `b` are different names (in different contexts) for the same type, usually written `a ~ b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's keep using the signature

```hs
(,) <$> length :: Foldable t => t a -> b -> (Int, b)
```

But change

```hs
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

to

```hs
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (x -> y) -> f x -> f y
```

so it doesn't get confusing. Clearly `f ~ (->) [a]` (assuming we're using the list instance of foldable) as you noticed, and thus `x -> y ~ b -> (Int, b)`, so `x ~ b` and `y ~ (Int, b)`. This is the part you missed, likely due to having confusing naming: the second argument is `f x` or `[a] -> b`, and you pass in `head`, which is `[a] -> a`. This **forces** `b` to become the same as `a`, otherwise the types wouldn't work out. The result is `f y`, or `[a] -> (Int, b)`, except `b` is now `a`, giving you the `[a] -> (Int, a)` signature.

Answer (score 2):

One way to derive the type of `(,) <$> length <*> head` is to abstract over `length` and `head` and consider instead the resulting lambda expression

```
\l -> \h -> (,) <$> l <*> h
```

of type

```
Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
```

with the types `[x] -> Int` and `[x] -> x` of `length` and `head` respectively we require

```
f a ~ [x] -> Int
f b ~ [x] -> x
```

and thus

```
f ~ (->) [x]  -- hom-functor aka Reader 
a ~ Int
b ~ x
```

which yields

```
([x] -> Int) -> ([x] -> x) -> ([x] -> (Int, x))
```

as type for the above lambda expression.

Comment: Thank you, @michid ! Appreciate the answer.

Comment: and we could also note that `\l -> \h -> (,) <$> l <*> h = \l -> \h -> liftA2 (,) l h = liftA2 (,)`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to derive the type of `(,) <$> length <*> head` is to work it out progressively by applying the definitions at every step:

```
(,)                     ::        a   ->       b -> (a, b) 
-- (<$>)                ::       (a   ->         c        ) -> f a -> f c
(,) <$>                 :: f      a   -> f    (b -> (a, b)) -- f a -> f c
--      length          :: [t] -> Int
(,) <$> length          ::             [t] -> (b -> (Int, b))
--            (<*>)     ::             f      (s -> q        ) -> f s -> f q
(,) <$> length <*>      ::  ([t] -> b) -> ([t] -> (Int, b))    -- f s -> f q
--                 head ::   [t] -> t
(,) <$> length <*> head ::                 [t] -> (Int, t)
```

The trickiest part is to correctly apply `(->) [t]` for `f` in the third and fourth step.

Answer (score 1):

We can try to arrive at some more easily understood formulation first, so that its type becomes "obvious". We have

```
       (,) <$> length <*> head
=
pure   (,) <*> length <*> head
=
liftA2 (,)     length     head
```

for *any* Applicative, by the Applicative laws and the definition of `liftA2`.

So we have `(,)` combining the contained / carried / produced results from the applicative values `length` and `head`:

```
              (,)
             /   \
            /     \
       length      head
```

But `length` and `head` are functions, and for functions we have

```
              (,)
             /   \
            /     \
       length      head
            \     /
             \   /
               x
```

i.e.

```
liftA2 (,)     length     head   x
=
       (,)    (length x) (head   x)
```

by the definition of the `(->)`'s Applicative instance.

Thus the type of `(,) <$> length <*> head` is the type of `liftA2 (,) length head` is the type of `\ x -> (length x , head x)`. And that is "obviously" "just" `[a] -> (Int , a)`.

GHCi concurs:

```
> :t \ x -> (length x , head x)
\ x -> (length x , head x) :: [t] -> (Int, t)

> :t (,) <$> length <*> head
(,) <$> length <*> head    :: [a] -> (Int, a)
```

`length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int` is defined for any Foldable but `head :: [a] -> a` works on lists specifically, so `length`'s type becomes specialized as `[a] -> Int`.

And `head` produces the same type that the elements of the input list have:

```
            (Int,a)        ~     (,) Int   a
             /   \                    |    |
            /     \                   |    |
       length      \       :: [a] -> Int   |
           \      head     :: [a] ->       a
            \     /            |
             \   /             |
              [a]          ~  [a]
```

So there's no "switching". Everything flows.